# WEBRTC How to capture video from camera library?

Tags: swift, webrtc, uiimagepickercontroller, webrtc-ios

Can't load video from a UIImagePickerController using WebRTC. 
With saved in-app Bundle file, it works, but if I use UIImagePickerController

```
UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:))
```

so I use mediaInfo like this:

```
(info[.mediaURL] as! URL).path
```

This code I use to start capturing a video file

```
   public func startCaptureLocalVideoFile(name: String, renderer: RTCVideoRenderer) {
        print("startCaptureLocalVideoFile")

        stopLocalCapture()

        localRenderer = renderer
        videoCapturer = RTCFileVideoCapturer(delegate: videoSource)

        guard let capturer = videoCapturer as? RTCFileVideoCapturer else {
            print("WebRTCService can't get capturer")
            return
        }

        capturer.startCapturing(fromFileNamed: name) { error in
            print("startCapturing error ", error)
            return
        }

        localVideoTrack?.add(renderer)
    }
```

so I get this media info:

```
info  [__C.UIImagePickerControllerInfoKey(_rawValue: UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL): file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/5F7A4469-5006-4590-8F59-396CD86A083B/tmp/trim.B46C5878-BAF2-432B-B627-9787D74CE7B0.MOV, __C.UIImagePickerControllerInfoKey(_rawValue: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType): public.movie, __C.UIImagePickerControllerInfoKey(_rawValue: UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL): assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=33EECFB7-514A-435A-AA19-26A055FB9F06&ext=MOV]
```

and this error:

```
startCapturing error  Error Domain=org.webrtc.RTCFileVideoCapturer Code=2001 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=File /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/5F7A4469-5006-4590-8F59-396CD86A083B/tmp/trim.B46C5878-BAF2-432B-B627-9787D74CE7B0.MOV not found in bundle}
```

Seems like it works with `Bundle.main` only, but we can't write to it.

Am I doing it right? Maybe there is another way to accomplish this? 
Thanks for the help!